# Update em várias linhas SQL server 2008 + PHP

Tags: php, sql-server

Como eu consigo fazer updates em múltiplas linhas com PHP no sql server?

Eu tenho uma estrutura parecida com isso, porém com muitas linhas:

```
ID     nome      vencimento
11  |  Joao   |  20/02/2014      
12  |  Arthur |  21/02/2014
13  |  Ana    |  22/02/2014
14  |  Kelly  |  23/02/2014
```

Gostaria de alterar a data de vencimento de cada usuário, acrescentar mais 30 dias.
Eu não sei como alterar múltiplas linhas, se fossem apenas 5 era mais fácil. Porém são 12 mil.

Como faço ?

Obrigado

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pode usar um `UPDATE` com [`DATEADD`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa258267%28SQL.80%29.aspx).

```
UPDATE tabela SET vencimento = DATEADD(d, 30, vencimento)
```

Comment: Muito obrigado, me ajudou muito.